# Mysqli Where Clause Error

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

When i use single where clause like `WHERE source_city = '$to_name'`, it work fine but when add another check it show me error:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

```
    <?php  
        if(isset($_GET["view"])){
            $to_name = $_GET["to_name"];
            $from_name = $_GET["from_name"];
            $select_user = "SELECT * from citi 
                WHERE source_city = '$to_name' AND
                dest_city = '$from_name'";
            $run_user = mysqli_query($conn,$select_user);
            if(!$run_user){
                echo "Error!";
            }
            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run_user)){
            $id = $row[0];
            $source_name = $row[1];
            $dest_name = $row[2];
            echo "
                    <br><br>
                    $id<br>
                    $source_name<br>
                    $dest_name<br>";

        }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: That error means you're not passing a valid result from `mysqli_query()`. Most likely you're generating a MySQL error. You need to find out what the MySQL error is - try echoing out your `$select_user` to see if the query you're running is valid (you can even run this direct using something like phpMyAdmin if you want to get the query right and get feedback as you do it).

Comment: Side note: Using string substitution in queries leaves your code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should consider using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Comment: add the mysql query in your question

Comment: Check table name and fields name in sql query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax for muliple `WHERE` statements is:

```
WHERE condition1 AND condition2 AND condition3
```

Using `OR` for completeness:

```
WHERE (condition1 AND condition2) OR (condition3 AND condition4)
```